# check the number of files before uploading (jquery)

Tags: jquery, upload

I am trying to check the number of files before uploading.
I want to allow 3 images only.

```
 <form   action="upload.php"   enctype="multipart/form-data"   method="post"> 
           <input type="file" name="image[]"  multiple="multiple" /> 
      <input type="submit"   value=" Upload "  class="submit"  />   
</form>

$(function() {
  $(".submit").click(function() {

      var numFiles = $("[name='image[]']", this)[0].files.length;

      if (numFiles > 3) {
               alert(numFiles);
         ;}     

    }); 

 });
```

This is the demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ld7fE/5/

How can I fix this issue?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".submit").click(function() {

      var _files = $("[name='image[]']").prop("files");

      if (_files.length > 3) {
           alert('not allowed');
               return false;
      }

    }); 

 });
```

---

EDIT >

```
$(function() {
  $(".submit").click(function() {

      var fileElements = $("[name='image[]']");

      var filesCount = $(fileElements[0]).prop('files').length;

      if (filesCount > 3) {
           alert('not allowed');
               return false;
      }

    }); 

 });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ld7fE/9/)

Comment: This is working fine but when I have 3 input file fields it does not work for the rest.
 <input type="file" name="image[]"  multiple="multiple" /> 
 <input type="file" name="image[]"  multiple="multiple" />

Comment: ok just consider this, $("[name='image[]']").prop("files"); you can change it to $($("[name='image[]']")[0]).prop("files");

Comment: Because I have got more than file inputs, the code does not recognise the other fields.

Comment: 2 files in each will be counted as just 2 for two inputs.

Comment: It has got the same result ... thank you for helping me.

Comment: you're welcome ,you know how to get files length so manage it out some how.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return false` from the event otherwise your form will still be submitted.

Try the following:

```
$('.submit').on('click', function() {  
    var numFiles = $(this).siblings('input[name="image[]"]')[0].files.length;

    if(numFiles > 3)
    {
        alert(numFiles);
        return false;
    }
});
```

[**jQuery Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ld7fE/7/)

Answer (score 0):

I solve it with this:

```
$("selector_for_file_input").get(0).files.length;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SGS3k/1/) with example.